# Parse Server Cloud Code - Update OR Create object

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I am using Parse Server on AWS and mLab with great success, except for my Cloud Code. The main issue is surrounding my previous code for **Create** OR **Update** an object. I used to do this by querying for a user pointer on the Favourites class. If a row contains a user pointer then I need to update its content, if it doesn't exist a row needs to be created.

**Old Parse.com Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveFavourites", function(request, response) {

    console.log(request.params.favourites);

    var Favourites = Parse.Object.extend("Favourites");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Favourites");

    query.equalTo('user', request.user);
    query.first({
        success: function(results) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

            console.log(results)
            if (results === undefined) {


                var favourites = new Favourites();

                favourites.save({
                    user: request.user,
                    favourites: request.params.favourites
                }, {
                    success: function(favourites) {
                        // The object was saved successfully.
                    },
                    error: function(favourites, error) {
                        // The save failed.
                        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                    }
                });

            } else {

                results.set("favourites", request.params.favourites);
                results.set("userId", request.user.id);
                results.save();
            }

            response.success(results);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            error.message("favourites lookup failed");
        }
    });
});
```

**New Parse Server Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveFavourites", function(request, response) {

console.log('user is : ' + JSON.stringify(request.user));

var Favourites = Parse.Object.extend("Favourites");
var query = new Parse.Query("Favourites");

query.equalTo("user", request.user);
query.first({
    useMasterKey: true
}, {
    success: function(results) {

        if (results && results.length > 0) {

            console.log('running found');
            favourites.set("favourites", request.params.favourites);
            favourites.set("userId", request.user.id);
            favourites.save();
            response.success();

        } else {

            var favourites = new Favourites();

            favourites.set("user", request.user);
            favourites.set("favourites", request.params.favourites);
            favourites.set("userId", request.user.id);
            favourites.save();
            response.success();
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not response unless callback finished. Set response.error on each Parse requests error.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveFavourites", function(request, response) {

    console.log(request.params.favourites);

    var Favourites = Parse.Object.extend("Favourites");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Favourites");

    query.equalTo('user', request.user);
    query.first({
        //is this query need masterKey?
        useMasterKey: true,
        success: function(results) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

            console.log(results)
            if (results === undefined) {


                var favourites = new Favourites();

                favourites.save({
                    user: request.user,
                    favourites: request.params.favourites
                }, {
                    success: function(favourites) {
                        // The object was saved successfully.
                        response.success(results);
                    },
                    error: function(favourites, error) {
                        // The save failed.
                        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                        response.error(error);
                    }
                });

            } else {

                results.set("favourites", request.params.favourites);
                results.set("userId", request.user.id);
                results.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(response.success, response.error);
            }


        },
        error: function(error) {
            error.message("favourites lookup failed");
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `verbose: error: code=101, message=Object not found.
verbose: error: code=141, code=101, message=Object not found.` even though there is a pointer to this user in the database.

Comment: Can you figure out "error: code=101, message=Object not found." is get from  which line?

Comment: Ok the query is successful and the error is on the PUT `verbose: PUT /parse/classes/Favourites/x3fOMoIOeo { 'user-agent': 'node-XMLHttpRequest, Parse/js1.8.5 (NodeJS 4.1.0)',`

Comment: Fixed, I had to do this `results.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(response.success, response.error);`